# Spanish site, some words translation still in English

Tags: language

I have a Wordpress installation, with the Spanish language set as the main language.

But I still see texts like "We found 6 results for your search" or like "Published" or "Categorized" displayed in English language.

Is there any way to modify these texts so that they are translated into Spanish?

Comment: Is this untranslated text in the admin or on the front end?

Comment: is in the front end

Comment: It probably means your theme is untranslated. If your theme is from wordpress.org you can provide translations at https://translate.wordpress.org. If your theme is not from the directory you will probably need review https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/internationalization/localization/ for guidance on how to translate themes, and you might want to contact the theme author to find out if the theme is ready for localization.

Comment: There are also translation plugins available, but plugin recommendations are off topic here.  Your theme will need to be localization ready to be able to use those plugins though.

Comment: Thanks, @JacobPeattie

Comment: My theme was developed starting from "Twenty Twenty-One" theme, will I be able to add translations on translate.wordpress.org?

Comment: What do you mean starting from? Is it a child theme? Or did you edit it to create a new theme? If it's the latter then no, you won't be able to translate it on wordpress.org.

Comment: Yes, it is the latter.
I found some strings on the /wp-content/languages/ folder.
thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what's happening is that whatever plugin/theme you are using "forgot" to translate those strings.

Translations in WordPress are handled by **Gettext**, you can learn more about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/).

If you really want to get your hands dirty and perform manual fixes to those untranslated strings you would need to find the string in the corresponding `.po` file and then recompile the `.mo` file, which you can do with an app like [POEdit](https://poedit.net).

This also means that you would need to know how to find the corresponding `.po` file by understanding the WordPress file structure and doing a bit of research on how said plugin/theme implements its translations, which is out of the scope of this question. Of course there are other alternatives, like using a plugin like [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) or similar, but plugins are also out of the scope of this question.